# How To Treat All Fields As Text (endless amount of fields) - Schema

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, schema

So the following code, reads in a tab delimited file in my datagridview, however the formatting is all over the place. One field in particular, is a sequence number, padded with zeros. After the import, all leading zeros go away leaving me with 1,2,3,etc. There is also a date field, after import it tacks on the time.

In theory, I need to treat every field as text on import. However, the number of fields on import could change. So one file might have 10 fields, the next file might have 200 fields.

Here's my connection string:

```
Dim ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Temp';Extended Properties='text';"
```

My schema includes the following:

```
Format=TabDelimited
TextDelimiter="
```

I've read where you can identify each field with a specific format. Very tedious to do this, especially if the fields can grow and shrink in size.

Suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like all columns as Text is fine - a numeric wont naturally display leading zeroes.  Are there any which **are** problematic as string? A DateTime type always has a Date and a Time - when you save/export just control the format.  I have a tool which dynamically generates the schema, you could do the same creating them all as text except for certain ones

Comment: Are the first  X columns  always the ones with a Date, the sequence ID and maybe one or two others which you'd rather not have as string?

Comment: The date fields are spread throughout the file. Treating all fields as text is the ideal way, I need to keep the format incoming as well as outgoing.

Comment: If they have the same name (we have to guess because we cant see the data), you could scan the column names to find them, and create a new DT with just those columns Typed.  Fairly easy since there is just one row.